# Getting different results from website in Neuralcoref?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using [Neuralcoref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) to find co-references. The [trial version of website](https://huggingface.co/coref/) is giving different results than the version which I have installed using `pip`. The versions are:

```
1. spacy==2.1.3 (as it will not work on spacy > 2.1.4)
2. neuralcoref==4.0
```

The code I'm testing upon is:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

# load NeuralCoref and add it to the pipe of SpaCy's model
import neuralcoref
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

# You're done. You can now use NeuralCoref as you usually manipulate a SpaCy document annotations.
doc = nlp(u'I love my father and my mother. They work hard. She is always nice but he is sometimes rude.')
print(doc._.coref_resolved)
```

It gives output:

```
I love my father and my mother. my father and my mother work hard. my mother is always nice but he is sometimes rude.
```

Similarly for this example:

```
# Input:

London is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames in the south east of the island of Great Britain, it has been a major settlement for two millennia. It was founded by the Romans, who named it Londinium

# Output:

London is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames in the south east of the island of Great Britain, the River Thames has been a major settlement for two millennia. the River Thames was founded by the Romans, who named the River Thames Londinium
```

In the first example, the problem is: it is not picking up `he` in the last as reference to father.

In the second example, the problem is: it is picking up `River Thames` in place of `London` which is wrong.

But the in website, both of the examples work fine.

[Example 1](https://huggingface.co/coref/?text=London%20is%20the%20capital%20and%20most%20populous%20city%20of%20England%20and%20the%20United%20Kingdom.%20Standing%20on%20the%20River%20Thames%20in%20the%20south%20east%20of%20the%20island%20of%20Great%20Britain%2C%20it%20has%20been%20a%20major%20settlement%20for%20two%20millennia.%20It%20was%20founded%20by%20the%20Romans%2C%20who%20named%20it%20Londinium)
[Example 2](https://huggingface.co/coref/?text=I%20love%20my%20father%20and%20my%20mother.%20They%20work%20hard.%20She%20is%20always%20nice%20but%20he%20is%20sometimes%20rude.)

Can't understand what is the difference?

Comment: You seem to be using the 'en_core_web_sm' model for Spacy. Neuralcoref uses features by the Spacy model. Can you try with the 'en_core_web_lg' model of spacy and check if it changes?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but the results are exact same as before after I used en_core_web_lg which was about `880mb` model.